# ObjectInputStream constructor hangs even though its counterpart ObjectOutputStream has been setup

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I am testing a simple TLS server and client which requires both an ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream to be set up at each end with the connection. I am aware that ObjectOutputStream must be setup before ObjectOutputStream for both the client and server and have written my code to accommodate this need, additionally I have tried flushing both ends prior to setting up the ObjectInputStream but this also blocks. This is my server code:

```
 public class ServerTask implements Runnable {

private KeyStore serverStore;
private char[] passwd;

public ServerTask(KeyStore serverStore, char[] passwd) {
    this.serverStore = serverStore;
    this.passwd = passwd;
}

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", "BCJSSE");

            KeyManagerFactory keyMgrFact = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
                    "PKIX", "BCJSSE");
            keyMgrFact.init(serverStore, passwd);

            sslContext.init(keyMgrFact.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

            SSLServerSocketFactory fact = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();
            SSLServerSocket sSock = (SSLServerSocket)fact.createServerSocket(2048);

            SSLSocket sslSock = (SSLSocket)sSock.accept();
            try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(sslSock.getOutputStream()))) {
                output.flush();
                System.out.println();
                try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(sslSock.getInputStream()))) {
                    System.out.println("here");
                } catch (IOException e) {}

            }catch (IOException e){
            }
            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This is my client code:

```
 public class ClientTask implements Runnable {

private KeyStore trustStore;

public ClientTask(KeyStore trustStore){
    this.trustStore = trustStore;
}

public void run(){
    try
    {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", "BCJSSE");
        TrustManagerFactory trustMgrFact =
                TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX", "BCJSSE");
        trustMgrFact.init(trustStore);
        sslContext.init(null, trustMgrFact.getTrustManagers(), null);
        SSLSocketFactory fact = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket cSock = (SSLSocket)fact.createSocket("localhost", 2048);
//            OutputStream outputStream = cSock.getOutputStream();
//            System.out.println("client");
        try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(cSock.getOutputStream()))) {
            output.flush();
            System.out.println();
            try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(cSock.getInputStream()))) {
                System.out.println("here");
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
}
```

How do I get the server and client to set up the ObjectInputStreams without blocking, what am I doing incorrectly? Thank you.

Comment: Works for me, with my keystores. Are you getting an exception?

Comment: very basic are you using the Thread.run() or Thread.start()?

Comment: Thread.start() . Marquis that's super weird, no It just hangs on either SSLSocket.startHandshake() or if I don't use that then on sending an object.

Comment: Not possible. It *throws an exception,* either on `startHandshake)`, or on `flush()` if you have it, otherwise on sending an object. With your current code you're just ignoring it. Probably a truststore issue, maybe even a keystore issue.